# Access kubernetes service from a docker container which is run by mesos

Tags: docker, dns, kubernetes, mesos

I have mesos-master (mesosphere/mesos-master) and mesos-slave (mesosphere/mesos-slave) running inside my Kubernetes cluster.

Mesos slave starts the docker containers (docker is accessed by mounting /usb/bin/docker from host) with my data processing application (short lived, 1-5 min) which needs to access other kubernetes services. So shortly speaking I need to access Kubernetes DNS from a container.

Is it possible to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found only one way:

I am resolving "kube-dns.kube-system" host into an IP address. Then I am injecting "metadata.namespace" into environment variable KUBERNETES_NAMESPACE. and finally I am passing --dns RESOLVED_IP and --dns-search ${KUBERNETES_NAMESPACE}.svc.cluster.local, so a mesos's docker container is able to talk to the services.